# How to export Gantt view to pdf?

Tags: odoo

I am using openerp 6.1 and I have created a project in which I have my phases and tasks in each phase.

I would like to print the gantt chart but there is no option there. Please advice how I can get this done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Their is default way out to have it on PDf but what you can always do is prepare one report to plot that report on pdf like Burn-down chart you have on project_scrum module, Using Pychart and reportlib engine, and you can produce effective result, or you can take moden web browser screen shot utility at the end.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I agree, there really should be print / PDF buttons for every page to save the current view :(

There are 2 workaround options I can think of:

1. Use reporting to generate your own report of the chart (I would suggest using the webkit_report)
2. Print the HTML view to PDF.. ie, capture the html code of the view and print it, or send to another system to convert to PDF (using wkhtmltopdf). I have an example here that might help you: http://timothysolomon.co.za/work/openerp-printing-with-javascript/

Good luck, maybe in version 7 they will have this by default.